# Install PostgreSQL with given admin password on Windows 7

Tags: windows, postgresql, windows-7

I would like to install PostgreSQL as part of my custom application installer.
Is there a way to install PostgreSQL without asking the user for a admin password, and to provide a custom admin password for PostgreSQL.

Later when the application needs to do some "admin" activities on the PostgreSQL DB the application knows what the password is.

Reason for this is, when the user supply the admin password for PostgreSQL during install time, the user will not remember it 6 months down the line when the application needs to do some admin functions on the DB, and the user have to supply the password.

Thank You

Comment: Are you referring to the password for the Postgres (Super)user or the Windows user running the service?

Comment: The password for the Postgres (Super)user.

Comment: If you run `initdb` "manually" during your installation you can (actually must) specify the superuser password

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official docs](http://www.enterprisedb.com/resources-community/pginst-guide#noninteractive), this can be done with the --superpassword  option when running the installer in unattended mode.

In general for what you are looking at doing, you probably need to run in unattended mode anyway (from your custom application's installer).  Additionally, you will probably find a lot of other very useful switches in that doc.

Best of luck.